# What is wrong with this Makefile? Needs to be run twice in order to work

Tags: docker, makefile

Running make once yields an error suggesting that `$(shell docker run -d $(IMAGE))` is not working as intended.

However running a second time works like a charm.

Seems like `make build-image build-api` causes the target build-api to not wait for the completion of build-image? Should i introduce a delayed execution? (the infamous sleep :D)

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: build

IMAGE := tensorflow-serving-grpc

build: build-image build-api

clean:
        -docker rmi -f $(IMAGE)

build-image:
        docker build -t $(IMAGE) .

build-api: CONTAINER_ID:=$(shell docker run -d $(IMAGE))
build-api:
        docker wait $(CONTAINER_ID)
        docker cp $(CONTAINER_ID):/usr/src/vendor ./
        docker rm -f $(CONTAINER_ID)
```

Comment: If the recipe for `build-image` should always run/complete *before* the recipe for `build-api` then `build-image` should be a dependency of `build-api`.

Comment: Doing a sleep is a really bad idea because different machines will work at different speeds, and what's good enough on one machine may not be good enough on another (or even the same machine running with a high load).   Picking a really big value means you have to unnecessarily wait, and still don't have a guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a target specific variable with a side effect, and you're making the incorrect assumption that the variable won't be expanded until the rule is run.    I would switch to using a bash variable, and concatenating the recipe to be run in a single shell as follows:

```
build-api: build-image
    CONTAINER_ID=$$(docker run -d $(IMAGE)); \
    docker wait $${CONTAINER_ID}; \
    docker cp $${CONTAINER_ID}:/usr/src/vendor ./; \
    docker rm -f $${CONTAINER_ID};
```

Another option is to create a target which creates the container id, and stores it in a file.   Make `build-api` dependent on this new target, and then in `build-api`, have each recipe line read the value from the file.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't wait then it's because you <s>allowed parallel execution with `-jN` option</s> run it from $(shell...). Using $(shell ...) should be avoided unless you know what you do.

You should also prevent parallel execution of `build-image` and `build-api` by declaring a prerequisite.

```
.ONESHELL:
build-api: build-image
    set -e
    CONTAINER_ID=`docker run -d $(IMAGE)`
    docker wait $$(CONTAINER_ID)
    docker cp $$(CONTAINER_ID):/usr/src/vendor ./
    docker rm -f $$(CONTAINER_ID)
```

Comment: Not quite -- the expansion of the target-specific-variable occurs before the recipe is run, regardless of any '-j' levels.   This will occur even if `build-api` is dependent on `build-image`...

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Ay, I forgot that people constantly misuse $(shell ...).